# Strange spaces between ForEach views SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have such code:

```
ForEach(listItems, id: \.self){ item in
                HStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        actionSheet()
                    }) {
                        HStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Image(item.img)
                            Text(item.title)
                                .modifier(TextHandler(fontSize: 16, rgbArray: [47,47,47]))
                                .padding(.leading,10)
                        }
                    }.padding(.all,20)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                .background(Color(red: listItemBack, green: listItemBack, blue: listItemBack))
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 16))
            }
```

and it results to:

[image]

why does views from this loop have this strange white spaces. But when I put into this loop only Text with some item data these spaces disappeared. Why does it happen? Maybe my paddings overlaps somewhere? I tried to use this code:

```
.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
```

but it didn't help me at all.

Comment: To which white space are you referring? In between the views or at the bottom? Also, it helps to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Between views of this list, at the bottom white space is connected with screenshot wrong cutting)

Answer (score 0):

It is the padding on your `Button` you have it at `(.all,20)`.

```
ForEach(listItems, id: \.self){ item in
                HStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        actionSheet()
                    }) {
                        HStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Image(item.img)
                            Text(item.title)
                                .modifier(TextHandler(fontSize: 16, rgbArray: [47,47,47]))
                                .padding(.leading,10)
                        }
                    }.padding(.all,20)                         
                    Spacer()
                }
                .background(Color(red: listItemBack, green: listItemBack, blue: listItemBack)). // This is causing the spacing. It needs to be moved to the parent view.

                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 16))
            }
```

If you want them spaced in a solid background without the white spaces, the background needs to go on a parent view. When I put your code into a `VStack`, and put the `.background` on the `VStack` I came up with this:
[image: VStack with solid gray background and a list of buttons]

Is this what you are looking for?

Edit: You have padding on the `Button` all the way around set to 20. That will make space around each of the buttons that are created. You then put your `.background` on each `HStack` that contains a `Button`. The `.padding` is going all around the button, but the `HStack` is only the height of the `Button`, not the `Button` and `.padding`. If you comment the `.padding(.all,20)` out, your will see the view collapse until the `Buttons` are right next to each other. I am sure you do not want that.

By putting the background on the parent view (in my case I put your code into a `VStack`, so the `.background` went there), you put one background behind all of the buttons, instead of one background per button with a gap.

2nd Edit:
Here is my minimal, reproducible example code. Note that I do not have access to your `listItemBack` variable to set the background color so I just used gray.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SpaceView: View {
    
    @State var listItems: [ListItem] = [ListItem(title: "First", img: "internaldrive"),
                                        ListItem(title: "Second", img: "paperplane"),
                                        ListItem(title: "Third", img: "scribble"),
                                        ListItem(title: "Fourth", img: "tram.fill"),
                                        ListItem(title: "Fifth", img: "clock"),
                                        ListItem(title: "Sixth", img: "a.magnify"),
                                        ListItem(title: "Seventh", img: "arrowshape.zigzag.forward")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        ForEach(listItems){ item in
                        HStack{
                            Button(action: {
                                print("\(item.title) Pressed")
                            }) {
                                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                    Image(systemName: item.img)
                                    Text(item.title)
//                                        .modifier(TextHandler(fontSize: 16, rgbArray: [47,47,47]))
                                        .padding(.leading,10)
                                }
                            }.padding(.all,20)
                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
//                        .background(Color(red: listItemBack, green: listItemBack, blue: listItemBack))
                          //.background(Color.gray) // Uncomment here and comment out the other background to see the difference.

                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 16))
                    }
    }
        .background(Color.gray) // Comment out here to switch between your view an my view.
    }
}

struct ListItem: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var img: String
}

struct SpaceView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SpaceView()
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, your screenshot is what I want to see, but when I tried to put my child views into VStack the final result didn't have full scr width, can you add pls the code of this screenshot for better understanding?

Comment: can you add some more info about your code for this img pls?

Comment: as I said before your solution looks like what I want to do, but I still didn't see any solution which is connected with your screenshot :(

Comment: This is why you should aways post a minimal, reproducible example. If you post a code fragment, you will get a code fragment back.